# Call a static method of a class derived from template without specifying template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, template-inheritance

I will try to explain my problem with a simple example:

```
class UselessClass {};

template<class RUNNABLE>
class Task : public RUNNABLE
{
public:
    static void StartScheduler()
    {
        //Start system scheduler
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
Task<UselessClass>::StartScheduler(); //Correct

//Task::StartScheduler();   //Wrong
```

What I want to do is write the following code: `Task::StartScheduler();`

Comment: How is compiler supposed to know the type of `RUNNABLE`?

Comment: But `Task` is not a class (It's a template for one). Hence you can't call any method on it (static or otherwise).

Comment: It is commonly said that a class is a blueprint for an object. Well, a class-template is a blueprint for a class, but it's not a class in itself.

Comment: The problem is that there are multiple versions of the static class function. One in each template instance. Which one, specifically, are you interested in invoking, here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Template is not a class, you can't call it without providing template parameters so that the compiler would know the exact type to call methods from.

When you try using `Task::StartScheduler();`, the compiler has no way to know what is the type of the `RUNNABLE` template parameter.

You can do something like this:

```
using UselessTask = Task<UselessClass>;
UselessTask::StartScheduler();
```

Though it is not exactly what you wanted,

Comment: But why doesn't the following code solve my problem? ```template<class RUNNABLE = UselessClass>``` ?

Comment: So if specifying the default value of the template, then why does the compiler not allow me to write:  ```Task::StartScheduler();``` ?

Comment: You need to write `Task<>::StartScheduler();`.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my previous comment, so just to reiterate: it works because this way you specify the default value of the template parameter so now the compiler know the type of `RUNNABLE`.

Comment: This seems to be a good alternative, but I still don't understand one thing, why do I have to write ```Task<>::```? usually when you specify the default template you can simply write ```Task::```. Why can't I do it in this case?

Comment: Because the way C++ compiler parses the code. It sees that `Task` is a template, not a class, and gives you an error since you can't call a method of a template or access a public variable of a template, only a `class` or `struct` (or `enum`). Maybe in future this will be simplified, but for now writing `Task<>` tells the compiler that you are using the concrete class, not the template itself.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know what else you'd like to know.